# Why does a reviewer who approves my edits get credit?

Tags: bug

I'm new to the Freelancing SE and don't have enough reputation to publish edits to a question. Yesterday, I edited the question for [Freelancer working in Asia for EU/UK companies](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3945/freelancer-working-in-asia-for-eu-uk-companies)

When I submitted the edits, I read the notice that these edits would need to be peer reviewed before they were published.

Today, my edits show up but are attributed to someone else, probably the peer reviewer. Is that how SE is intended to work or is this a bug?

Comment: Your edit was good and substantial, but I removed a further part of the question (the thanks + signature lines). The system applied your edit first, then mine when I selected "Improve Edit..." in the review queue. You're still attributed in the revisions: https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/revisions/3945/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mod who approved the edit also edited it further (removing signature-style lines).

Your edit was accepted, so you should have received your +2 reputation points, and you have credit on it.

Comment: It's wrong to attribute one person's work to someone else.

Comment: True, but you got your attribution, and the next editor did more editing, and is more recent.

Comment: Now I see. I tried reading up on Edits in the help but didn't realize that the edit history was available. Thanks for taking the time to explain.